# Definition of Algebraic Function Field

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, function-fields

the definition of algebraic function field $\mathbf{F}$ over $\mathbf{K}$ that I know is the following:

There exists an element $x \in \mathbf{F}$, transcendental over $\mathbf{K}$, such that $\mathbf{K}(x) \subset \mathbf{F}$ is a finite extension.

I want to show that the latter implies that $\mathbf{K} \subset \mathbf{F}$ has a transcendence degree $1$ and is finitely generated.

Does this fact have a nice proof?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: $\mathbf{F/K}$ has transcendence degree 1 follows from additivity of transcendence degrees in tower: $\operatorname{tr.deg}(M/L)+\operatorname{tr.deg}(L/K)=\operatorname{tr.deg}(M/K)$.  Finitely generated also follows from a similar statement.

Comment: @user10354138 Thank you!